# Chrome(webkit) gradient percentage bug

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

**BUG! Left here in hope that it will attract attention and perhaps a fix.**

The problem is that chrome, makes(i have checked!) the first half of the gradient smaller than the second one. My code is:

```
background: linear-gradient(to left, #ffffff 50%, #f5f5f5 50%) fixed;
```

Also tried:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#ff3236), color-stop(50%,#ff3236), color-stop(50%,#000000), color-stop(100%,#000000));
background: linear-gradient(to left, #f5f5f5 0%,#f5f5f5 50%,#ffffff 50%,#ffffff 100%);
```

Edit/Update: It is indeed a bug - updates are for clarity (top 2 blocks are divs, each 50% width, of screen - bottom is split with gradient):
1) Visual representation of the bug: [image]

2) Thanx to @elstgav for a putting up the a [Codepen Test](http://codepen.io/elstgav/pen/guotz)

Comment: "Seems to be" or actually is? Have you checked the element widths in Dev Tools?

Comment: Yes, it is bigger. I have checked.

Comment: Reasonable question. We can't diagnose images. and we don't have access to 'your device'. Perhaps a fiddle at reasonable size that demos the issue.

Comment: try this way... maybe it could work: background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 50%,#f5f5f5 50%,#f5f5f5 100%);

Comment: No. I did try that before and just now as well.

Comment: Curiosity... if that's not really a gradient... why don't you give each cell a plain color?

Comment: Because that pattern is actually a background that alternates and expands beyond the container that the cells are in. In short, design constraints.

Comment: There is a fiddle that you can check. Also if you copy and paste the code into a local file and then open it with Chrome - you will see that the problem will be visible on smaller containers as well.

Comment: This appears to be bug with Chrome. I've created a code pen to highlight the bug: http://codepen.io/elstgav/pen/guotz

Comment: Looks like there's already a bug report for this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=419344

The bug doesn't appear in Safari or Firefox

Comment: @elstgav I came to the same conclusion and submitted a bug report as well soon after i posted this (about 2 months ago). It's awaiting confirmation. - meaning it's dead in the water unfortunately. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=408542 If you can and want to you could vote for it, perhaps it will attract some attention.

Comment: @elstgav Ah, i see you linked the codepen test on the latest report. Also it seems to be assigned to someone for fixing. Good news :)

Comment: They marked it as fixed, but I am still struggling with percentage and linear gradients: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=408542

Comment: Apparently it's a resurgent issue. Gets fixed and then appears again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now (2016-11-02), This issue ssems to be fixed, I just tested these pens `:`

http://codepen.io/elstgav/pen/guotz

http://codepen.io/gliesche/pen/GoWMVO

in Chrome Version 54.0.2840.71 m,
and they all work.

However, Chrome still seems to have some issues with scaling gradient backgrounds when they are repeated:

SO link: [Chrome not updateing background-size gradient properly on resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675890/chrome-not-updateing-background-size-gradient-properly-on-resize)

Chrome BT: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=604875