# Chrome not updateing background-size gradient properly on resize

Tags: css

While Firefox does this right, updating the `linear-gradient` background on every frame, chrome seems to render things in "jumps", meaning it will only render a mathematically correct layout once every few pixels after resizing.

[**Demo playground**](http://jsbin.com/tokuvo/edit?html,css,output) 
*(Try resizing the window)*

```css
/* draw 10 horizontal responsive lines in the background */
div{
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent calc(100% - 2px), #000 100%);
    background-size: calc(100% / 10); /* 10 rows */
}
```

#### Background-size not updated properly on Chrome (GIF):

[image]

#### On Firefox, as always, everything works great:

[image]

---

This is a simplified problem. I am trying to create a grid using a responsive css background gradient, but in Chrome this proves difficult.

*I am trying to avoid using a lot of HTML markup to accomplish this, since the grid size is so dynamic.*

Anyone knows a trick to help Chrome render the background-size properly while the grid resize itself? 
Thanks.

---

### Update - issued as a new [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=604875)

Comment: Looks like a rounding issue and might be related to this [chromium issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=419344).

Comment: @michaPau - seems like it. Although that one is classified `fixed`. I wrote in the comments it does not seems fixed. Thanks for finding this one!

Comment: Don't think so. If it would be rounding error, so it would appear also on width settings. But these seems ok. Look [here](http://codepen.io/jannahody/pen/WwJdxd?editors=1100)

Comment: Maybe the specific function which handles background-size on resize is not well written and is different than the one which handles other rendering of properties. who knows

Comment: @vsync Please include this knowledge your comment in Chrome. If necessary, even my link with which the behavior can be reproduced.

Comment: It was opened as a [new bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=604875), please vote :)

Comment: this bug causes serious issues on chrome, and especially mobile chrome, background gradients are "cut off" when desktop users resize their window, and worse on mobile, whenever the user scrolls to hide chrome's address bar, but chrome is failing to update the background following this viewport resizing, and so basic scrolling leaves a gradient failure visible on the bottom of the page.. the following standard technique suffers this problem (the only workaround seems to be avoiding bg gradients) `html, body { height: 100%; background: fixed no-repeat linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black); }`

Comment: @ChaseMoskal - please harass the Chromium team with a comment and a star in the link to the bug I had posted.

Comment: alright i said my peice :)

Comment: we've got to check if they've fixed it, later today i'll try to remember to see if it reproduces in Canary

Comment: confirmed -- i verified that the bug still exists in canary